# Time consumption of functions of a process in linux

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, perf

We are porting our application from solaris to linux. Few workflows in linux application are taking more time than solaris application. I have used solaris studio profiler to analyze at function level that gives me time consumed by each function. But in linux I explored perf tool, I could not find out How can  I attach perf to a running application and did not find out any command which will print the time consumed by each function of a process. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching to a process is done by using the `-p` option in `perf record` (from `man perf-record`):

```
   -p, --pid=
       Record events on existing process ID (comma separated list).
```

So assuming that your process has ID 12345, you can attach to it with (enabling call-graphs with `-g`):

```
perf record -g -p 12345
```

perf will then automatically write `perf.data` when the process terminates. You can then examine the file by calling

```
perf report
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am able to attach to a running porcess and generate perf.data file. perf report gives lot of info , I am not sure which command or flag gives me time taken by each function. There is lot of info in the report.

Comment: @user2328412 with the `-g` option, the `self` column should provide information on the percentage of time that was spent in each function (the `Children` column sums up all times of the subcalls). With the ncurses interface provided by `perf`, you should be able to navigate through the call tree. For me, it's sorted by the `Children` column. BTW, you can use `--no-children` in `perf record` to see the `self` percentages only.